# How to Calculate From 2 Tables in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following 2 tables:

```
A (ID, No1, No2,D)
B (ID, No3, No4,D)
```

And table data is following:

A Tabel Data

```
ID = 1, No1 = 23, No2 = 45, D = 1
ID = 2, No1 = 12, No2 = 5, D = 1
ID = 3, No1 = 14, No2 = 4, D = 1
ID = 4, No1 = 41, No2 = 12, D = 1
ID = 5, No1 = 2, No2 = 25, D = 1
ID = 6, No1 = 3, No2 = 96, D = 1
```

B Table Data have not any Data

If I Pass Following SQL query

```sql
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS  No3Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
FROM dbo.A LEFT 
OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id
GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

then following Data is coming

```
No1Sum = 95, No3Sum = 0,  Diffrence = 95
```

But When I Add `WHERE` condition and write query then no data is coming in the following query

```sql
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS No3Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
FROM dbo.A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
WHERE (dbo.A.D = 1) 
AND (dbo.B.D = 1) GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

If data will precent in both tables then Result will show for example

```
No1Sum = 95, No3Sum = 10, Diffrence = 85,
```

If I give following query

```sql
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS No3Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
FROM dbo.A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B 
    ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
    AND dbo.A.D = 1 
    AND dbo.B.D = 1 
GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

then Following Result is Showing

```
No1Sum = 570, No3Sum = 0, Diffrence = 570
```

(it is summing 6 times as A Tables has 6 Rows)

So how to calculate from both tables, when data in both tables result is accurate, but when A Table has data and B has no data then the result is not coming.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: You just want to sum table B if there is same ID at A table?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, what particular data you are using and what particular result you are expecting, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this query does not work is because it only returns records where dbo.b.d is 1. But in your query it can sometimes by null.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS No3Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
FROM
         dbo.A  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
WHERE   
         (dbo.A.D = 1)  AND (dbo.B.D = 1) GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

So change this line

```
(dbo.A.D = 1)  AND (dbo.B.D = 1) GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

To this

```
(dbo.A.D = 1)  AND (isnull(dbo.B.D, 1) = 1) GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

isnull(arg, default) is set to arg if arg is not null otherwise it sets it to default.

Comment: Thanks Its Working .... One More Question .. In My Question I was Added Only One Condition on D = 1 ... If Want to Get Data From Both Tables On Two Condition WHERE A.ID = 1 AND A.D = 1 AND B.D=1... How to Add This Condition.....

Comment: If I understand correctly you should be able to say `A.ID = 1 and dbo.A.D = 1  AND (isnull(dbo.B.D, 1) = 1)`

Comment: Yes, My Main Problem is I want to Calculate From 2 Table. Table A as Purchase And B Table As Sale. In My Both 2 Tables There is a Fix Condition That D will 1 and Some Time It will change to 2 or So on and i want to Use Only Those Records Where D is 1... Now I want to Take The Balance Qty of My Product.. When I Make Purchase Entries (TABLE A) and Dont have Sale Entries (In Table B) Condition is Same... So As per Your Answer it woking.. But As i want to Calculate Balance So It Will Depend on Id. For Example A and B Id Has ProductId So I Want the Diffrence of that.

Comment: @imran Khan maybe you want to say `group by dbo.A.ID`?

Comment: No, I Want to Diffrence From A and B Where A.Id = B.ID AND A.ID = 10 as i told ID is Product id. Suppose In Table A.Id Which is 10 Has 5 Records and B.Id of 10 Has No Records , I Need  Sum of A No1 - Sum of B No3 WHERE D =1 AND A.Id = 10. When Data In A and B then Result is Comming But When No Data in B, 0 Rows Coming.. That the Main Problem.

Comment: @imran khan Why don't you post a new question? Basically there's not room to post the entire answer here. Here's most of it: select aid, isnull(no1, 0), isnull(no3, 0), isnull(no1 - no3, 0) from 
(select a.id aid, sum(dbo.A.no1) no1 from a group by a.id) a left join
(select b.id bid, sum(dbo.B.no3) no3 from b group by b.id) b on aid = bid

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do , even if Second table has data .

```
SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum ,
            ISNULL(SUM(B.No3), 0) AS No3Sum ,
            ISNULL(SUM(A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
    FROM    A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

---

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) AS No1Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS No3Sum, 
    ISNULL(SUM(dbo.A.No1), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(dbo.B.No3), 0) AS Diffrence
FROM dbo.A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
WHERE (dbo.A.D = 1) 
AND (dbo.B.D = 1) GROUP BY dbo.B.No3
```

This query will not fetch any records if table `B` do not have any data ,because of this condition .

```
 WHERE (dbo.A.D = 1) AND (dbo.B.D = 1)
```

and i think applying multiple conditions on join is overhead.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B 
    ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
    AND dbo.A.D = 1 --Overhead
    AND dbo.B.D = 1 --Overhead
```

Comment: I Also Used This ;;; LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B 
    ON dbo.A.id = dbo.B.id 
    AND dbo.A.D = 1 --Overhead
    AND dbo.B.D = 1 --Overhead

Comment: For Example in a Table has 6 Rows and B Tabels has not any row then it will Sum 6 Times..... Kindly Read Last 2 Paragraph of My Question I was Already Maintioned..