# I can't get the result for the inner join

Tags: sql

please i want to get the result from the combination of two entities(Corporate Partners and Direct Sales Agent) in which i have specified the columns. These two entities are connected to another entity through a look-up (Direct Sales Manager) which act as the filter.

This is the Code here

```
  SELECT
  Filterednew_corporatepartner.new_cpid AS CorporatePartnerID 
  ,Filterednew_corporatepartner.new_name AS CorporatePartnerName
  ,Filterednew_corporatepartner.new_shortcode_cp AS CorporatePartnerShortcode
  ,Filterednew_directsalesagents.new_agentcode AS DSAAgentcode
  ,Filterednew_directsalesagents.new_name AS DSAName
  ,Filterednew_directsalesmanager.new_name AS DSMName
  ,Filterednew_directsalesmanager.createdon AS CreatedOn
FROM
  Filterednew_directsalesmanager
INNER JOIN Filterednew_directsalesagents
ON Filterednew_directsalesmanager.new_name = Filterednew_directsalesagents.new_directsalesmanagername

INNER JOIN Filterednew_corporatepartner
ON Filterednew_directsalesmanager.new_name  = Filterednew_corporatepartner.new_dsmname


 WHERE (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.createdon >= @StartDate) AND (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.createdon <= @EndDate) AND (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.new_name IN (@DSM))
```

Comment: Please try to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for others to help you better

Answer (score 0):

check Filterednew_directsalesagents and  Filterednew_corporatepartner Tables there is some value are null when you adding

```
WHERE (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.createdon >= @StartDate) AND (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.createdon <= @EndDate) AND (Filterednew_directsalesmanager.new_name IN (@DSM))
```

Condition that's why your are not getting result.

My Suggestion is use left outer join instead of inner join

**UPDATE :** Just Check this link I was surfing same problem.

[How to Calculate From 2 Tables in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828983/how-to-calculate-from-2-tables-in-sql)

Comment: I tried changing the INNER JOIN as suggested but it still not giving the expected result. but when i remove the WHERE clause i get result but i need the filter to be there